# run boxfuse images on a self hosted solution

Tags: cloudcaptain

I just found Boxfuse. It is a really interesting solution for dev and shipping applications. There is one point that botheres me. Can I run boxfuse images on a self hosted solution with kvm or something like that?
Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

No, currently Boxfuse supports VirtualBox / Hyper-V (dev) and AWS (test & prod).